# how to get standalone android studio and sdk to install on a USB?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to get a standalone android bundle so that i can keep it in a USB and use it on any computer.
I don't want to carry my laptop to my college everyday I tried doing that but I had to download SDK on every PC which isn't exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: This might be helpful to you. http://ftcforum.usfirst.org/showthread.php?4512-Running-Android-Studio-from-USB-Flash-drive

Answer (score 0):

for the Android studio in the usb view **go in the bottom of the page,you'll find the no installer option** ,click [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#tos-header)

however JDK (Java Development Kit) are not, which is required to run AS. So you still need to install JDK in each computer you use.